# Site where you can submit your Scala code and have it reviewed

Tags: scala, review

Does anyone know of a site, newsgroup, message board, etc. where I can submit some of my Scala code to have it "reviewed" by experienced Scala developers? The code works and whatnot, but I'd really like to learn to be more idiomatic when coding Scala, and often I find myself reverting to more imperative like development because I can't find a "better way."

Comment: Try http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try on [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Thanks, I was not aware of Code Review. That being said, I do have one problem with it. According to their FAQ you should post all of your code in the question, but in my case I'd like to upload a small project (about 800 LOC) and have someone glance through it in its entirety. Reason being that some of the portions I believe I'm doing  correctly might not being idiomatic.

Answer (score 3):

My advice is to upload your project to github - make sure to add copyright and licensing information. Then post the one or two relevant short snippets on Code Review and link to your project on github.

Note that there are plenty of questions here on stackoverflow where users have asked to turn something that is imperative to something more functional or idiomatic. The key is to break down your problems into distinct issues you're trying to solve then take the one that has the most chance to get an answer and ask a question about it. If you can make it self contained then that really good. See https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=relevance&q=%5bscala%5d%20%20idiomatic for some ideas...